# Minitest Spec with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, specifications

I start a project in Rails 4 but i can't do the test what I want.
In Rails 3 I use minitest::Spec but in rails 4 thats not work
I read some tutorials than say thats possible but anything what i try fail

this is the error that

> NoMethodError: undefined method `decribe' for main:Object

nothin that i try works
Someone can help me use Spec syntax on minitest on Rails 4?

I already try a lot of gems

```
gem "minitest-rails"
gem "minitest"
gem "minitest-spec"
gem "minitest-shouda-rails"
```

Comment: Well it should work.  The error message above has a typo. Decribe vs describe ?

Comment: just a missing 's' decribe -> deScribe (facepalm)